# R conditional join

Tags: r, join, conditional-statements, tibble

is there a way to join and update column in R? Example:

```
tbl1 <- tibble(ID = LETTERS[1:3],
       VAL = rep(NA, 3),
       tbl1_df = list(tibble(A = rnorm(3),
                             B = rnorm(3))))

tbl2 <- tibble(ID = LETTERS[1:3],
               VAL = c(1, 2, 3),
               tbl2_df = list(tibble(A = rnorm(3),
                                     B = rnorm(3))))

tbl3 <- tibble(ID = LETTERS[1:3],
               VAL = c(1, 2, 3),
               tbl3_df = list(tibble(A = rnorm(3),
                                     B = rnorm(3))))
```

I want to join these tibbles together and update VAL with one of the tables that have values. Tables will always have same values in VAL, but I don't always know in which table they are. Is there away to force VAL columns together or keep VAL column from one of the tibble where values exists?

Answer should look like this and as mentioned, it doesn't matter which table VAL column comes from, tables have identical VAL or NA.

```
tibble(ID = LETTERS[1:3],
                 VAL = c(1, 2, 3),
                 tbl1_df = list(tibble(A = rnorm(3),
                                       B = rnorm(3))),
                 tbl2_df = list(tibble(A = rnorm(3),
                                       B = rnorm(3))),
                 tbl3_df = list(tibble(A = rnorm(3),
                                       B = rnorm(3))))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  ID      VAL tbl1_df          tbl2_df          tbl3_df         
  <chr> <dbl> <list>           <list>           <list>          
1 A        1. <tibble [3 x 2]> <tibble [3 x 2]> <tibble [3 x 2]>
2 B        2. <tibble [3 x 2]> <tibble [3 x 2]> <tibble [3 x 2]>
3 C        3. <tibble [3 x 2]> <tibble [3 x 2]> <tibble [3 x 2]>
```

Comment: `reduce(list(tbl1, tbl2, tbl3), full_join, by = "ID") %>% select(ID, VAL, tbl1_df, tbl2_df, tbl3_df)`

Comment: I like this, but selecting VAL just happens to work in example. As mentioned, I don't know what tables have VAL column populated. Maybe I have to wrangle it from there, if nothing else. As Full join returns VAL.x, VAL.y and VAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```r
library(purrr)

list(tbl1, tbl2, tbl3) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = "ID") %>%   #merge all tables
  select_if(~!all(is.na(.))) %>%     #drop columns having all NA value
  select(-starts_with("VAL."))       #keep only one 'VAL' column and drop remaining repetitive columns
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  ID    tbl1_df          tbl2_df            VAL tbl3_df         
  <chr> <list>           <list>           <dbl> <list>          
1 A     <tibble [3 x 2]> <tibble [3 x 2]>  1.00 <tibble [3 x 2]>
2 B     <tibble [3 x 2]> <tibble [3 x 2]>  2.00 <tibble [3 x 2]>
3 C     <tibble [3 x 2]> <tibble [3 x 2]>  3.00 <tibble [3 x 2]>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this will do. I had *mutate(VAL= rowMeans(select(., starts_with("VAL")), na.rm = TRUE)* and then select, but this is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Building on comments from Jaap, you can combine the tibbles into a single tibble by using the reduce command from purrr with a full_join from dplyr.
The issue is then how to just get the VAL which exists, instead of having 3 columns for VAL not all of which have data.  An easy way to do this is using the coalesce command from dplyr, which takes the first non missing value.  An issue introduced in this step is that the data types are BOOLEAN if they are all NA, so this is addressed by using as.numeric.  Finally the additional VAL columns that have a letter added after are deleted.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

reduce(list(tbl1, tbl2, tbl3), full_join, by = "ID") %>% # Combine the tibbles into a single tibble
  mutate(VAL= coalesce(as.numeric(VAL.x), as.numeric(VAL.y), as.numeric(VAL))) %>% # Create a variable for VAL which takes the first non missing using the coalesce function
  select(-starts_with("Val.")) # Delete the columns for VAL which were created when joining and have a name of VAL. and then a letter
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.